# Word choice for a health-monitoring app: patients, clients, dependents, other?

Tags: terminology, wording

I'm designing the UX for a healthcare app, to help carers remotely monitor elderly patients.

The word currently being used (in the prototype) to describe the elderly is "dependents" but it has [negative connotations](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/dependent)

Is there a better word to refer to them?

The primary target audience for the app is professional carers, however they're not doctors, so I'm not sure that "patients" is the right word, and "clients" feels a little cold.

To make things extra complicated, the secondary target audience for using the app is loved ones or family members.

Comment: Is this not too broad?

Comment: Hey @David, I dunno, is it? I'm a novice contributor. Please elaborate and I'll see if I can amend the question to suit. :)

Comment: I’m not too sure myself. Waiting for guidance. I’d have thought it was though, as content and copywriting are skills within their own, and require their own psychology.

Comment: Oh! I get it, sorry, I thought the question was directed at me. Cool, will wait to hear further input.

Comment: You may want to ask this question on the English Language and Usage stack exchange (https://english.stackexchange.com/). They can help you find an appropriate word with a proper implication.

Comment: Hey @Wanda, thanks for the advice. I was going to but I saw a couple of similar questions closed as off-topic because apparently it breaks this rule: [Out of scope: Naming, including naming programming variables/classes](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Interesting, I'd expected them to also cover finding words that have the proper 'load' to it. Especially in your case you're looking for a word that describes the client without sounding offensive, cold or otherwise negative. I see plenty of 'how do I call' questions there. Or perhaps they haven't been moderated yet..

Comment: I think you may be able to focus the wording of your question more towards "synonyms that evoke specific feelings" rather than "needing a word for a UI" to get a better response from the English stack exchange

Answer (score 3):

How about:

**Care Recipient**

or just

**Recipient**

for situations where you don't have a lot of space for the label. The person receiving the care. Very clear without the drawbacks that you've already mentioned. It's not as "cold" as client because it keeps the focus on the care being given.